# Get all role names in ASP.NET MVC5 Identity system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

MVC5 uses a new Identity System. How can I get all role names?

I try do access it via `IdentityStore` but without success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found that you can use the `DbContext` via the `IdentityStore` instance and use the well-known method `.Set<T>()`.

This works for me:

```
var identityStore = new IdentityStore();
foreach (var role in identityStore.DbContext.Set<Role>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(role.Name);
}
```

Comment: I am on MVC 5 but cannot find the IdentityStore

Answer (score 29):

This is a bit more intuitive

```
var roles = dbContext.Roles.OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's currently no way to do enumeration style methods via the identity interfaces, that will be coming in a future update targeting administration scenarios(post 1.0 RTM), so there's no way to enumerate all users or roles via the Identity APIs.  That said, you can always drop down to EF or whatever the store implementation is to directly enumerate the roles/users.

Comment: Do you have any links or public info on the admin scenarios for Identity? Thanks.

Comment: @Hao Kung "that will be coming in a future update targeting administration scenarios(post 1.0 RTM)" I'm currently building some admin pages for administrating users and roles. I see that the nightly builds have the class member Roles but the RTM hasn't. I was just wondering when the next update will be? Are we talking 3 months, 6 months, a year, longer? Thanks.