# How to obtain a list of Users from ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

**Edit: This question is outdated**

The Identity Framework was a moving target at the moment I asked this. The authors changed quite a few things and they have decoupled several others, making everything easier.

Have a look at the [Asp.NET Identity Sample project on github](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample).

---

I'm creating a small application that requires user management. Registration is not allowed, instead there is a super user that will create and modify login information.

I'm using the new [ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx) membership system, and sure enough, creating users and adding roles is easy and intuitive.

Now, my question: How to obtain a list of users using the AuthenticationIdentityManager class that is used by the generated AccountController class? I couldn't find a way to access the user list from my controller.

(By the way, the new name "Identity" may sound awesome to some people but it is a pain to search for.)

**Edit**: If I try to do this

```
ApplicationDbContext UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
UsersContext.Users.ToList(); // Exception
```

I get an exception `Invalid column name 'Discriminator'`. The definition of ApplicationDbContext is generated automatically by the new application wizard:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace Cobranzas.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : User
    {

    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContextWithCustomUser<ApplicationUser>
    {

    }
}
```

So my guess is that `Discriminator` column is for telling apart `ApplicationUser` from `User`. However, it does not exists in my database (which was created automatically by the application.)

Comment: Have you looked at the sample application? https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/master/AspnetIdentitySample

Comment: There is nothing there to get a list of users. I already have a working application, I just need a list of all users.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found out that I wasn't using the derived `ApplicationUser` object for anything, so I just went ahead and changed all uses of it for plain old `User`. Then I just changed `ApplicationDbContext` definition for the following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<
    User, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin,
    Role, UserRole, Token, UserManagement>
{
}
```

And now I can access the user list:

```
UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
...
UsersContext.Users.ToList();
```

However, I think this will come back and haunt me in the future (I'll probably need to add more fields to `User`) so probably I'll have to use the same approach as in this question:

[Get all role names in ASP.NET MVC5 Identity system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18638425/7841)

**Edit**: Since I got the need to add a new property, I had to revert my changes. So I went ahead and did a line by line comparison with the ASP.NET Identity Sample Project, and found out that the generated project had the following line:

```
IdentityManager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore());
```

while the Sample application had included the database context in the constructor. So I added it in my constructor, recreated the database and the problem went away.

```
IdentityManager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

Comment: This got me as well. I do not understand at all why the included VS2013 RTM template is configured this way. Could there possibly be a reason or is this an oversight?

Comment: And wait to see what's up when you update the RTM versions with the 1.0 ones. Everything was changed; fortunately, the sample application was also changed to reflect this.

Comment: You mean RC to RTM? are you referring to this sample app? https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Take a look at [this commit](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/commit/776680f37657affff109a1107c90cde4963d2eb2#diff-eb7df5aa8f2b1fb32e562813c8c4e650) - I had to change my application to fit the new architecture. It took me a couple of hours but it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You just saved my bacon! I've been trying to use MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers(), but it kept returning nothing, even with users in my table. My app is using ASP.NET Identity, so Membership is probably accessing a deprecated table with no users. I already had the context set up, so literally all I had to do was take your lead and invoke the context, grab its users, and cast to a list. BOOM! It's working beautifully. After looking a 20+ S.O. pages, I'm glad I held out for this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

1. Create `ASP .NET MVC5` project by default
2. Create `ASP .NET Identity` tables properly and change **connection string** as well.
3. To get users just do the following test
   A. Go to `AccountController`
   B. Create any dummy method and put there

> ```
> var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
>
> var allUsers = context.Users.ToList();
> ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Please consider that this question is outdated. [This comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773838/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-users-from-asp-net-identity/20954972?noredirect=1#comment31171316_18833772) may be of interest.

Answer (score 4):

For RTM, you will have to drop down to your `DbContext` or whatever your specific store implementation has to enumerate all users.  In the next release, we will most likely be adding an optional `IQueryable` Users/Roles method on the Manager classes that stores can implement to expose `IQueryables` for both users and stores.

Comment: Thank you. Right now I'm using `IEnumerable<IRole> rolesForUser = await IdentityManager.Store.Roles.GetRolesForUserAsync(user.Id, CancellationToken.None);` which smells funny to my untrained nose.

Comment: It will be great to have methods to Delete(remove) in addition to the IQueryable Users/Roles methods you mention.  Now UserManger Delete user method is lacking.

Comment: These are available now in the 2.0-alpha1 release

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

        var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var Users = db.Users.Include(u => u.Roles);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can use the following type of `Constructor` in `Identity` `AccountController`.

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager,
            ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
{
      UserManager = userManager;
      AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
}

public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
     get
     {
          return _userManager ?? Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
     }
     private set
     {
          _userManager = value;
     }
}
```

then we can directly used `UserManager` object to get user list like

```
var userList= UserManager.Users.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by explicitly setting right types:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
IQueryable<IdentityUser> usersQuery = userManager.Users;
List<IdentityUser> users = usersQuery.ToList();
```

Imoports:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```