# How can I get all users with ASP.NET Identity based on a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I trying something quite simple but for whatever reason it does not work, and for that reason I here to see if something gives me any light, and I could not find examples or solutions somewhere else (Bing/google)

The problem is quite simple I am using a slightly modified ApplicationUser class:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual Guid BusinessId { get; set; }
}
```

With the following helper (Extension method):

```
public static Guid GetBusinessId(this IIdentity user)
    {
         var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
         var currentUser = manager.FindById(user.GetUserId());

        return currentUser.BusinessId;
    }
```

Then finally the method that is "causing" the issue:

```
public IQueryable<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

        Guid businessId = this.User.Identity.GetBusinessId();
        var users = userManager.Users.Where(u => u.BusinessId == businessId);

        return users;
    }
```

What happens here is that when I query Users, I get nothing but it should at least get the current logged in User, since he has the proper businessId.

If I put a break point on the users query and try anything like "ToList()" or "ToList()[0]" on the immediate window I get the following:

```
?users.ToList()
Count = 1
[0]: Could not evaluate expression
?users.ToList()[0]
An internal error has occurred while evaluating method System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item().
```

Any ideas why, or is there a "right" way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the internal error (inner exception)?

Comment: I get no exception, what you see above is the result from the immediate windows that I copied and pasted entirely.

Comment: Did you check that businessId has a valid value? (e.g. is not Guid.Empty)

Comment: Yes I did, it does have a value that executed on SQL Manager to confirm it was supposed to return one record

Answer (score 1):

have a look here [How to obtain a list of Users from ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773838/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-users-from-asp-net-identity) qouted from answer

> > I found out that I wasn't using the derived ApplicationUser object for anything, so I just went ahead and changed all uses of it for
> >     plain old User. Then I just changed ApplicationDbContext definition
> >     for the following:
>
> ```
> public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<
>     User, UserClaim, UserSecret, UserLogin,
>     Role, UserRole, Token, UserManagement>
> {
> }
> ```
>
> And now I can access the user list:

```
 UsersContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
 ...
 UsersContext.Users.ToList();
```

> However, I think this will come back and haunt me in the future (I'll
>   probably need to add more fields to User) so probably I'll have to use
>   the same approach as in this question:
>
> Get all role names in ASP.NET MVC5 Identity system
>
> Edit: Since I got the need to add a new property, I had to revert my
>   changes. So I went ahead and did a line by line comparison with the
>   ASP.NET Identity Sample Project, and found out that the generated
>   project had the following line:

```
IdentityManager = new AuthenticationIdentityManager(new IdentityStore());
```

> while the Sample application had included the database context in the
>   constructor. So I added it in my constructor, recreated the database
>   and the problem went away.

Comment: I could not find the IdentityManager nor AuthenticationIdentityManager that he talks about, and the first example does not work since I have a modification on the ApplicationUser