# How to find users by custom property in .net identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

My `ApplicationUser` class has a property called `CompanyID`.

All users are tied to a specific company. Now I'd like to list user accounts by `CompanyID` but can't figure out how to do it, `UserManager.findxxx` seem to be limited to whats built in and I can't seem to query it about custom properties.

Comment: What is the name of your DbContext ? see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773838/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-users-from-asp-net-identity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incase you extended the `User` model class with the `CompanyId` field:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

var usersByCompanyId = context.Users.Where(user => user.CompanyID == 1234).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

use bottom code for get custom **ApplicationUser** in identity with custom property

```
var context=new AuthContext();
var result=context.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>.SingleOrDefault(item => item.NationalCode == "");
```