# Display all users in aspnet identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

This is my applicationDbContext class:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
```

and this is my controller action method to retreive all the users with their user name:

```
   public JsonResult GetUsers()
    {
        var ret = (from user in db.Users
                   orderby user.Id
                   select new
                   {
                       UserName = user.UserName,
                   }).AsEnumerable();
        return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now, i am running into a problem.Whenever i execute, i got this problem----**Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'App.Models.ApplicationUser'.**

I have seen this so questions [How to obtain a list of Users from ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18773838/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-users-from-asp-net-identity?lq=1). What is the simplest approach to solve this error.Should i follow the solution given in above question. i have already customized my user id property from string to int.

Comment: Everything was running fine before but once i tried the above code, it started giving me multiple objects sets Error. Strange thing is that i have removed the above code but still the same error.how is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have added this to your ApplicationDbContext:

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

while through inheritance you already have it in IdentityDbContext:

```
public IDbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
```

Simply remove the ApplicationUsers and it will work

Comment: The error clearly says you *do*. It says you have an object set named `ApplicationUsers`. That needs to go away.

Comment: Yes try searching for this set.