# I have roles Seeded - but Roles.GetAllRoles doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-identity-2

Ok I have seeded some roles which can be found in the SQL database in the table AspNetRoles
and the users can be found AspNetUsers.

I have also found a bunch of aspnet_ tables (I think they are old WebForm ones). Within a view I am calling @Roles.GetAllRoles() which is returning no results. the aspnet_Roles table has no records. So it may be checking there. But that seems unlikely as the seeded roles are being created thusly:

```
 var roleManager = new RoleManager<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Member"))
              roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Member"));
```

Which in my little knowledge of MVC5 would suggest that Roles.GetAllRoles() would return the correct result.

I am using this @model EUWebRole.Models.IdentityManager also tried ApplicationUser with no change in results.

So to the questions:

1) How do I get the list of Roles?
2) If I am using the wrong "tables" how do I set it so that it is using the correct tables?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You're aspnet_tables are old from either the default MembershipProvider or the SimpleMembershipProvider (either way it doesn't matter they should be removed).

MVC 5 uses Identity 2.0 by default.  If you need to do anything with roles you need to use the [RoleManager](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started).

Comment: That's what I thought but - Roles.GetAllRoles() is still returning nothing.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sorry Roles is depreciated, checkout [Get all role names in ASP.NET MVC5 Identity system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633040/get-all-role-names-in-asp-net-mvc5-identity-system)